# Copy-Item -Exclude перезаписывает файлы

Tags: powershell

Не могу понять почему файлы все время перезаписываются, в документации написано что параметр -Exclude не даст этого

```
$username = "admin"
$password = "pass!"
$secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr
$servers = Get-Content -Path .\servers.txt
foreach ($server in $servers) {
    $session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred
    Copy-Item -FromSession $session (Join-Path "C:\bp\" "*") "D:\test\" -Exclude (Get-ChildItem "D:\test\") -Recurse
  }
```

Comment: Так в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item?view=powershell-7.1) вроде бы сказано, что параметр действует **только** тогда, когда фильтра задан, например, маской **"D:\test\\*"**

Comment: Copy-Item : Путь содержит недопустимые знаки.
строка:1 знак:1
+ Copy-Item -FromSession $session (Join-Path "C:\bp\" "*") "D:\test\*"  ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (D:\test\*:String) [Copy-Item], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CreateDirectoryArgumentError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Comment: при добавлении маски выдает ошибку

Comment: В документации сказано, что Параметр **Exclude** - это строка, а не объект - перечень файлов каталога. Мне кажется, Вы неправильно используете, данный параметр

Comment: Попробуйте так -exclude [String[]]((Get-ChildItem C:\tmp -File).Name)

Comment: не выходит, пробовал по разному как вы предложили